# Timer trigger never runs when creating with terraform

Tags: azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

My function works fine if I create all the resources via the portal. However timer trigger never kicks off if I create everything with terraform. I have spent a couple of days comparing all the resource settings terraform vs. portal to make sure everything is 1:1.

How do I troubleshoot a timer never kicking off?

I have checked the log stream and the ping is working but timer never runs. Using consumption plan. Deploying via az cli zip deployment. Using functions v3. Cron expression is set to run every two minutes. I only have one function inside this app.

Comment: without showing any code or Terraform config, how should we be able to help you?

Comment: Could you show your terraform template?

Comment: Yes please. Please show terraform template/the fix I would upvote if it was there.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the function app version setting